# EditText replacing character after appending

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I'm trying to make a number look like this

932-874838/9

I did this with my EditText to append the `-` and `/` after some spaces

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(text: Editable?) {

            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                onValueChange(s.toString())
            }
        })
}
private fun onValueChange(value: String) {

        mNumberTxtView.text = value

        if (value.length == 3) {
            mNumberTxtView.append("-")
        }

        if (value.length == 10) {
            mNumberTxtView.append("/")
        }
    }
```

When I'm typing like

> 932

it automatically appends the `-` , and that works, but after it appends the `-` and if I type another number it replaces the `-` with that number instead of continuing, so it becomes `932-` at first but when trying to put another number,

> 932**8**

it gets replaced like that removing the appended `-`

I think the problem is inside the `onValueChange()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`onValueChange`** should be like this:

```
var test: StringBuilder = StringBuilder()
var lastValue: String = ""

fun onValueChange(value: String) {

    if(lastValue.length > value.length) {
        test.deleteCharAt(test.lastIndex)
        if(test.length == 3 || test.length == 10) {
            test.deleteCharAt(test.lastIndex)
        }
    } else {
        test.append(value.last())

        if (test.length == 3) {
            test.append("-")
        } else if (test.length == 10) {
            test.append("/")
        }
    }

    lastValue = value
    textView.text = test
}
```

Comment: There is just one problem, when I delete one number it keeps adding numbers to the text and crashes

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 1):

Try this, instead.

```
private fun onValueChange(value: String) {

    if (value.length == 3) {
        mNumberTxtView.text = "${value}_"
    } else if (value.length == 10) {
        mNumberTxtView.text = "${value}/"
    }

}
```

Let me know if this works.

(The curly brackets around "value" in the strings may not be necessary. I'm still getting used to Kotlin's way of handling string concatenation.)

Edited to remove redundant and potentially loop-causing part.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change text in `beforeTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged` to prevent re-call of those methods by `TextWatcher`. Make changes in `afterTextChanged`.
But be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively.

So set invoke of `onValueChanged` into `afterTextChanged` method

with removal of `mNumberTxtView.text = value`